Show that $I(\gamma) = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\gamma x} \, dx$ is continuous
Let $I(\gamma) = \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\gamma x} \, dx$. Show that $I$ is continuous for $\gamma > 0$.
My approach: let $\gamma_n$ be a decreasing sequence such that $\gamma_n \to \gamma$. We want to show that $I(\gamma_n) \to I(\gamma)$. For that, we call $f_n(x) = x^2e^{-\gamma_nx}$ and we see that $f_n(x)$ is non-negative and measurable for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (since it is a composition of continuous functions).
Since $\{\gamma_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence, we have that $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ and clearly $f_n(x) \to f(x)$. Therefore, we can use the monotone convergence theorem which gives us
$$\text{lim}_{n\to \infty}I(\gamma_n) = \text{lim}_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\gamma_n x} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty}\text{lim}_{n\to \infty}\ x^2 e^{-\gamma_n x} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty}x^2 e^{-\gamma x} \, dx = I(\gamma)$$
Is my solution for this exercise correct? I am particularly unsure whether I can just state that $\{\gamma_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence.
Any help or feedback would be highly appreciated by me!

Why not make the argument more elementary? It's very common to forget $u$-substitution exists, and trying $t=\gamma x$ gives $$I(\gamma) = \frac{1}{\gamma^3}\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-t}dt$$ which is a function of $\gamma$ times a constant.

Wouldn’t that prove it to be continuous on the right? I would use dominated convergence on compact ntervals

@julio_es_sui_glace could you be maybe a bit more precise? How would you use the dominated convergence theorem?

On the interval $[a,b]$ it is dominated by $x^2 e^{-ax}$ which is integrable

Not only is is continuous, but more!  $I(\gamma)$ is an analytic function of the complex variable $gamma$ in the right half-plane.  (Use Morera's theorem.)

Why not make the argument more elementary? It's very common to forget $u$-substitution exists, and trying $t=\gamma x$ gives
$$I(\gamma) = \frac{1}{\gamma^3}\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-t}dt$$
which is a function of $\gamma$ times a constant. This is a very useful technique for integrals with nonelementary answers as it's much easier to prove an integral converges than to compute one.

Thank you, I really like your answer! The reason why I tried to use one of the convergence theorems is that we have studied them in the course which is why I assumed that I should use them for those exercises.
